# Handle www-authentication request using ajax?

Tags: .net, ajax, authentication

Is it possible to pass credentials using AJAX to a webserver that request www-authentication?

I want to log in to a website that uses .NET Bsic www-authentication, and pass the credentials using ajax. When visiting the server with a browser, the browser prompts the user with an authentication/login window.

The html header contains this:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
realm="hosting.xp"
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 6.0.2.6568
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I want to access the site 'behind the scenes' by calling it from an ajax object, but I'm not sure how to handle the http header that requests the authentication.

I would like the ajax call to result in a specific user being logged in (the cookie set) so that the user can procedd to the site later and be 'already' logged in.

can this be done in the way I describe here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the username and password in the URL like so:

http://username:password@example.com/secure

Here's an example with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.logMeIn').click(function(){
        $.get('http://username:password@example.com/secure', null, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });
});

</script>

<a href="#" class="logMeIn">Log me in!</a>
```

Comment: This would pose a problem if the password has something other than alphanumeric characters in it...how would you work around that?

Answer (score 0):

With http-authentication there is no need for cookies, the credentials are kept by the browser, or in your case for the initial request, by your javascript state.